# Samsung Xpress M2026 on Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: printing

I have problem with my priter Samsung. I install driver this way:

1. I downloaded uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz
2. in terminal: `tar zxvf uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz`
3. `sudo ./uld/install.sh`
   and everything went ok, driver was install.

Then I went to settings and add new printer as default printer. When I wanted print test paper there was:

```
usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl not available: No such file or directory
```

so I copy rastertospl and rastertospl c files in /usr/lib/cups/filter by using this:

1. `cd /usr/lib/cups/filter/`
2. `sudo ln -s rastertosplc rastertospl`
3. `sudo ln -s rastertospl rastertosplc`

but this doesn't help. Now I see:

```
usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I try also add ppd file in settings but this doesn't work too.

Does anybody have idea how solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

please see here to install SAMSUNG ULD printer drivers: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/samsung-clx-3305-laser-drucker/

Note: the driver will be shown as "M2020-Series", but it works also for M2026.